# scikit-learn - can a LinearRegression() learn something different to a straight line using one feature?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am using scikit-learn's LinearRegression() with time-series data like

```
time_in_s              value
1539015300000000000    2.061695
1539016200000000000    40.178125
1539017100000000000    12.276094
...
```

As it it a univariate case I expect my model to be a straight line like **y=m*x+c**. When I do

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.time_in_s,
                                                    df.value,
                                                    test_size=0.3,
                                                    random_state=0,
                                                    shuffle=False)

regressor = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred_train = regressor.predict(X_train)
y_pred_test = regressor.predict(X_test)
[...]
```

I get a straight line asn expected: [image]. If I use `shuffle=True` though, I get a curve [image].

I am struggling to understand what `shuffle` does here and why can I learn something different than a straight line with one feature. I'd appreciate a hint.

EDIT: Here are the model's attributes

```py
>>> #shuffle=False
>>> print(f"{regressor.coef_}")
[-1.6e-16]
>>> print(f"{regressor.intercept_}")
272.0575589244862

>>> #shuffle=True
>>> print(f"{regressor.coef_}")
[-7.76e-17]
>>> print(f"{regressor.intercept_}")
143.9711420915541
```

And for plotting:

```py
start = 61000
stop = 61500

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))

color='tab:red'
plt.plot(df.index[start:train_length].values.reshape(-1, 1),
         df.value[start:train_length].values.reshape(-1, 1),
         color=color)
color='tab:blue'
plt.plot(df.index[train_length:stop].values.reshape(-1, 1),
         df.value[train_length:stop].values.reshape(-1, 1),
         color=color)
color='tab:green'
plt.plot(df.index[start:train_length].values.reshape(-1, 1),
         y_pred_train[start:],
         color=color,
         linestyle='dashed')
plt.plot(df.index[train_length:stop].values.reshape(-1, 1),
         y_pred_test[:stop - train_length],
         color=color,
         linestyle='dashed')

ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting a curve. If you check the [help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for train_test_split, it writes:

> shuffle bool, default=True Whether or not to shuffle the data before
> splitting. If shuffle=False then stratify must be None.

I assumed your data is ordered according to `df.time_in_s`, so you are running a regression model on the first 70% on your data and predicting on the last 30%, if you don't shuffle.

With `shuffle=True`, the order of the rows are swapped and you are taking a random 70% of the data and predicting on another 30% of the data, without considering the time. You did not show the code for plotting, but my guess is you plotted the original data frame, with ordered time, and just placed the predictions on top, hence you get this fuzzy line.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try printing out your regressor.coef_ and regressor.intercept_ for both cases?
Also how are you plotting the data?
Linear regression can only give you 1 weight and 1 bias if your input is 1D. The shuffle parameter only shuffles the data you pass it, this cannot make your model higher dimensional.